# How to add FIXED PRODUCT TAX programmatically in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i want to add/update FIXED PRODUCT TAX for products programmatically  , i am working with csv product upload. here i need to save FIXED PRODUCT TAX for the product.
please guide how should i do this programmatically in magento

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that fpt is your fixed product tax attribute

```
$product->setFpt(
    [
    [
        "website_id" => 0,
        "country" => "EN",
        "state" => "*", // optional
        "price" => 200.0000

    ]
    ]
);
```

then save

```
$product->save();
```